# Url Parameters and specific syntax

Tags: solr, extjs4

I am trying to pass parameters via URL using: `setParams({id:id,model:mod})` , and in the browser’s address bar I see `localhost/MVC/query?id=1&model=member`. It is successful.

But I want to pass parameters that in url bar will look like: `localhost/MVC/query?fq=model: member+model:new_member`. I am trying to integrate “Solr” search server, and this is the syntax that supports for filtering queries.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at `Button#getHref()`:

```
getHref: function() {
    var me = this,
        params = Ext.apply({}, me.baseParams);
    params = Ext.apply(params, me.params);
    return me.href ? Ext.urlAppend(me.href, Ext.Object.toQueryString(params)) : false;
},
```

and the `toQueryString()`:

```
toQueryString: function(object, recursive) {
    ...
    for (j = 0, ln = paramObjects.length; j < ln; j++) {
        ...
        params.push(encodeURIComponent(paramObject.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(String(value)));
    }
    return params.join('&');
},
```

So I think you should write a new version for `toQueryString`, assumed it is `toSolrQueryString` to use `:` instead of = and `+` instead of `&`. Finally you override the `getHref()` to use `toSolrQueryString` function in your Button. Remember the return should be:

```
return me.href ? Ext.urlAppend(me.href, 'fq=' + toSolrQueryString(params)) : false;
```

Comment: One more notice is you still can use `Ext.Object.toQueryString(params)` to get the string, then apply `replace()` function to get your style of Solr query string instead of writing a brand new function `toSolrQueryString()` above